# Can not visit bintray.com after trying to publish my library to bintray

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter

During my first open source android library publishing,
After added this to build.gradle and it syncs successfully:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
}
```

However,when i am going to visit bintray.com,there are very strange errors indicating errors for bintray.com's SSL certificate.I guess the installed bintray plugin has done some routing ,but after i close andorid studio the problem persists.

Even more weird: when i use my cell phone to access the website the same thing happens!

[image: err]
[image: err 1]

Comment: Currently bintray.com isn't experiencing any known ssl issues.   You should contact Bintray's support for further investigation.

Comment: It happened to me as well. When i login with github, it was succesful. But when i navigate to other page it logs-out automatically